# Simple Ansible module fails to run with "Unsupported parameters" error. Probably something silly

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

I am trying to learn how to build a module.  The goal is to be able to send variables to be processed by a module and return the result as a different variable to be used in a jinja2 template.  I think I am missing something very basic and I can't find any examples that highlight what I am doing wrong.

This is my first try in building a module and I have little python experience. 
 I am running Ansible 2.7 with Python 2.7.  I have looked at several examples on the web and the Ansible documents so I think I am close but I am not understanding how to pass the variable correctly or how the python commands work within the module.

Here is the playbook: split.yml

```
    - hosts: localhost

      tasks:
      - name: split a coumpound variable into parts
        split:
          excel: 'data1 data2'
        register: result

      - debug: var=result
```

And here is the module in library/split.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

    def main():
        module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={})
        splitcell = (excel.split()[0])
        module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=splitcell)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Here is the error when running the playbook:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "invocation": {
>           "module_args": {
>               "excel": "data1 data2"
>           }
>       },
>       "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (split) module: excel Supported parameters include: " }
>           to retry, use: --limit @/root/ansible/split.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************** localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0
>   failed=1

I also tried a different function with similar results:

Playbook: processip.yml

```
    - hosts: localhost

      tasks:
      - name: Test ip module
        processip: ip_string="192.168.0.2/24"
        register: result

      - debug: var=result
```

Module: library/processip.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    import ipaddress
    from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

    def main():
        module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={})
        get_netmask = {ipaddress.IPv4Interface(ip_string).netmask}
        module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=get_netmask)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Error output:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "invocation": {
>           "module_args": {
>               "ip_string": "192.168.0.2/24"
>           }
>       },
>       "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (processip) module: ip_string Supported parameters include: " }
>           to retry, use: --limit @/root/ansible/processip.retry
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ************************************************************************************************************************************************** localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0
>   failed=1

For try number 1 I was simply trying to pass a variable "data1 data2" and split it at the space and return the first string in the list (data1)

The second attempt was to take an IP address 192.168.0.2/24 and process it with the python ipaddress module to return 192.168.0.2 255.255.255.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have told Ansible that your module takes no arguments:

```
module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={})
```

If you want to accept an `excel` argument, you need to declare that in your code:

```
module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={
    'excel': {'type': 'str', 'required': True},
})
```

In your code, you attempt to access a variable named `excel`, but no such variable exists.  You could get the parameter value like this:

```
excel = module.params['excel']
```

With these changes, your module would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *

def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec={
        'excel': {'type': 'str', 'required': True},
    })
    excel = module.params['excel']
    splitcell = (excel.split()[0])
    module.exit_json(changed=False, meta=splitcell)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And running your example would produce:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "meta": "data1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  So some silly questions (maybe).  So in the playbook, you have to send the variable to the module and from the module you have to accept the variable, correct?  If I wanted to return that data as a variable to be used elsewhere in the playbook or in an associated jinja2 template, is there a different module.exit that would just send back the variable?  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to pass data to a module you do that via module parameters, and the module must be configured to accept those parameters.  You are already returning data from the module with the `exit_json` call, which you then record by using `register`. That is pretty much how it works. You can return an `ansible_facts` dictionary which will instantiate new facts, but I have found that is almost never what you want do do (because it complicates calling your module multiple times).